# webservice @POST returns 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, jboss7.x, resteasy

I made webservice on jboss-as-7, which works ok with @GET method, but when I tried to add @POST, I'm getting "415 Unsupported Media Type". After a lot of code tweaking on client & server side, now I'm just using REST client for testing. Am I missing here something?

webservice:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
@Path("/RESTService")
public class ReservationsResource {

    @EJB
    private ReservationsSB reservationsSB;

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    @Path("/reservation/{id}")
    public Reservations getReservation(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        return reservationsSB.getReservation(id);
    }

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/xml")
    @Path("/reservation/delete")
    public Response deleteReservation(Reservations r){
        edited = null;
        reservationsSB.deleteReservation(r);

        return Response.status(201).entity(r).build();
    }
```

entity:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@Table(name="reservations")
public class Reservations {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String date;
    private String owner;
    private int active;

    @ManyToOne
    private Tables table;

    public Reservations(String date, String owner, Tables table, int active) {
        super();
        this.date = date;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.table = table;
        this.active = active;
    }
        ...
}
```

REST client request:
url: `http://localhost:8080/BarBar/RESTService/reservation/delete`
body(same as is returned by getReservation()):

```
<reservations>
<active>1</active>
<date>2014-01-14 21:00:00.0</date>
<id>23</id>
<owner>dqf</owner>
<table>
<capacity>6</capacity>
<id>30</id>
<name>table 4</name>
</table>
</reservations>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to set your `Content-Type` and `Accept` headers to *application/xml*. Also, this isn't necessarily critical, but consider setting your method to `@DELETE` to use the appropriate REST semantics.

Comment: Thank you so much! Accept header was missing

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!